# ERROR: Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to work with angular material but when I tried to import MatButtonModule after installation it's showing **error TS2305: Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatButtonModule'**.
Please help with this.

```
package.json and package-lock.json:
`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },`
```

main.ts:

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I am trying to use material but "MatButtonModule" is not working, I wanted to know why it's showing module is not exported.

Comment: have you imported it in app.module?

Comment: Check this sample project for detail: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-button?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared-material.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a src/app/app.module file

in this you need to import the module

```
 import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
```

and also in your NgModule imports array (same file)

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        MatButtonModule,
    ],
```

Comment: thanks @Ego Placebo, there was a silly mistake I did, I was doing import but was writing '@angular/material'; and not '@angular/material/button';  
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help, I frequently encounter frustrating little syntax errors with Angular! Love working with it but it can be tricky to track down issues due to how rapidly it is evolving!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ego's answer, this is because the `@angular/material` root entry-point no longer exports any modules from Angular Material v9+, requiring you to instead import from the appropriate sub entry-point (first deprecated in [v8.0.0](https://github.com/angular/components/releases/tag/8.0.0):)

> Importing directly from the root `@angular/material` entry-point is deprecated. You should instead
> import from specific entry-points, e.g. `@angular/material/button`. This aligns with `@angular/cdk`,
> makes clear where symbols originate, and helps safeguard against including unused code. **The
> deprecated style will be removed in Angular v9.**

So your `MatButtonModule` import from the `@angular/material` entry-point would've been previously valid in v8.0.0 or older.